# Everything You Do Is a Balloon - meaning

Tags: meaning, boards-of-canada

[Boards of Canada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boards_of_Canada) have released a song entitled *Everything You Do Is a Balloon* that appeared on [*Hi Scores*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hi_Scores).

Has it ever been officially explained by the duo what does that song title mean? Or is it just supposed to be a silly name?

Answer (score 8):

It appears to be [a personal story](http://bocpages.org/wiki/Everything_You_Do_Is_A_Balloon), as stated in the first published interview '[The Age of Aquarius](http://bocpages.org/wiki/The_Age_of_Aquarius)' of the band, conducted by [The Cosmic Crofter](http://bocpages.org/wiki/The_Cosmic_Crofter).

> *... Some titles are personal stories, such as 'Everything You Do Is A
>   Balloon', which was a realization made long ago in the forest".*

Comment: That's a nice find, thank you very much, however unfortunately it seems that there isn't a full explanation of the title anywhere

Comment: You're welcome. And yes, I searched for quite some time, but this is the only 'official' thing I could find. Of course there has been speculated much by fans, but as far as I can see this is never confirmed by the band itself.